# Problem with understanding output in bash code

Tags: bash, sh

I have following code in bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
w=`who | grep $1`
if [ -z "$w" ]; then
echo "$1 ... ";
fi
```

Could you help me to understand the output of this code.
I can see that it will display given parameters from command line ($1, $2...)

But I don't really understand these 2 lines:

```
w=`who | grep $1`
if [ -z "$w" ]; then
```

Could you provide me with some help as I cannot really find much information

Comment: Note that unless you actually want to print `$w`, you can just change the condition to `if who | grep -q "$1"` (`-q` suppresses the output of grep).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me a script to check if the username you pass as parameter to the script is logged on the system.

For example if you call it with `./check.sh nonexistinguser` it will print `nonexistinguser ...`.

Explanation:

```
w=`who | grep $1`
```

Execute `who`, which displays who is logged in, then `grep` the result for whatever parameter you passed to the script (`$1`), store the result in a variable called `w`; have a look [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) for the docs on `-z`

```
if [ -z "$w" ]; then
```

If `"$w"` has length zero, execute the body of the if.